# Swift calculating a new point x distance in y direction

Tags: swift

I'm doing some code in sprite kit and want to calculate a position of a sprite based on a start location and moving it In a given direction and distance. For example, assuming I'm using degrees with 0 meaning straight up, I want to move the sprite from it's current position in the 45 degree (up and right) direction 10 points.

Trigonometry isn't my strength and I've been struggling to figure out how to apply it. Moving in the 45 degree direction seems pretty straight forwards, but I'm not sure how to calculation for directions like 110 (down and right) or 225 (down and left).

My first attempt looks like this:

```
public func offset(byDistance distance:CGFloat, inDirection degrees:CGFloat) {
    let vertical = sin(degrees) * distance
    let horizontal = sqrt(pow(distance, 2.0) + pow(vertical, 2.0))
    self.position = self.position.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX:horizontal, y:vertical))
}
```

But I don't think it's working as the results look like this:

```
Direction 45, distance 88.26 -> New location {75.10, 115.88}
Direction 135, distance 88.26 -> New location {7.79, 88.60}
Direction 225, distance 88.26 -> New location {-82.09, 120.53}
Direction 315, distance 88.26 -> New location {65.76, 110.06}
```

Can anyone give me some clues as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few clues:

1. `sin()` takes radians not degrees, so you need to convert.
2. `0` is right, not up so you need to adjust for that.
3. use `cos()` for horizontal.

This is closer to what you need:

```
public func offset(byDistance distance:CGFloat, inDirection degrees:CGFloat) {
    let radians = (degrees - 90) * .pi / 180
    let vertical = sin(radians) * distance
    let horizontal = cos(radians) * distance
    self.position = self.position.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX:horizontal, y:vertical))
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. Trig was always something I struggled with at school because I always had problems trying to understand how it worked. I've been coding for over 30 years now and it still drives me nuts trying to understand it. I'm still reading internet sites on maths so I'll keep plugging away :-)

Comment: I think the one big thing I missed was that the functions work in radians. All the math sites I'd looked at worked in degrees. I also noticed that if I used the OS X calculator, it uses degrees by default where as if I type in 'sin(45)' or similar in OS X's Spotlite search, it uses radians.

Comment: iOS and Mac OS trig functions ALWAYS use radians. Most sites that describe trig functions use degrees because they're more intuitive. If you understand that the circumference of a circle is 2∏ • radius, and you assume the radius is 1 unit, you can think of an ant walking along the outside of the circle. If it walks ∏/2 units, it will have traveled 1/4 of the way around the circle. Once it's walked ∏ units, it will be halfway around the circle. When it's walked 2∏ units, it will have completed a full circle. That's how radians work.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 (actually 3, but let's ignore the 3rd) separate notations for trigonometric functions like sine and cosine: Degrees and Radians. Both describe angles. Degrees range from 0 to 360, and radians range from 0 to `2π`.

Converting between them is trivial:

```
degrees = 180 * radians / π
radians = degrees / 180 * π
```

iOS and Mac OS use radians for their trig functions.

You can either continue to track your angles using degrees and then convert to radians before feeding the values into your trig functions, or convert to using radians.

If you understand that the circumference of a circle is `2π • radius`, and you assume the radius is 1 unit, you can understand radians by thinking of an ant walking along the outside of the circle. The total path along the circumference (outside) of the circle is `2π` units in distance. If the ant walks `π/2` units, it will have traveled 1/4 of the way around the circle. Once it's walked `π` units, it will be halfway around the circle. When it's walked `2π` units, it will have completed a full circle. That's how radians work.

Comment: Man, the pi symbol in the SO font is ugly! The lower-case pi looks like 2 Ts, and the upper-case PI looks like an upside-down U. Both are barely recognizable. The lower case pi in the code font is the only one that looks halfway decent.

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer simpler way without trigonometry - you can use point distance:

```
func CGPointDistanceSquared(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return (from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y)
}

func CGPointDistance(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return sqrt(CGPointDistanceSquared(from: from, to: to))
}
```